# Busy signal when muting myself on Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

When I am on a call and press my Mute button, I cannot hear anyone besides a "call waiting" tone. This only happens when I am connected via Bluetooth on my desktop. It works fine on Bluetooth on my phone.

Comment: Does this also happen when using CTRL+SHIFT+M to mute or unmute?

Comment: This isn't a Teams behavior, so maybe something strange with your bluetooth headset/driver? To be clear, are you pressing mute on the blutooth device or in Teams? Try and check whether teams still sees and uses the bluetooth device under Ellipses > Device Settings > Audio Settings when you mute, and/or see if changing it back and forth improves things? Also test using the web app vs the desktop app if you can.

Comment: @harrymc yes, it happens when using keyboard shortcuts as well.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale This happens when I click on the Mute button in Teams. I can reproduce the behavior while making the "test call" in the Settings -> Devices -> Make a test call.  When I click on mute, same behavior, I can't hear the test caller's voice and I hear the tone.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and reinstall Teams?